# Parse large ASCII matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, import, string-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I am parsing a large ASCII sparse matrix, output of PETSc, but my current implementation is impossibly slow. I don't know how I could speed that up.

The ASCII file of a sparse PETSc `aij` matrix is as follows (with `col` being an integer index, and val being a floating point, e.g., `1.372e-1`):

```
row0: (col, val) (col, val) ...
row1: (col, val) (col, val) ...
row2: (col, val) (col, val) ...
...
```

What I did right now is simple: with a text editor I remove the `rowX:` part and then use the following code:

```
(* Open and split into lines *)
Ktxt = StringSplit[Import["K.txt"], "\n"]

(* convert ASCII exponents *)
convert[s_] := ToExpression /@ StringReplace[StringSplit@s, "e" | "E" :> "*^"]

l = {}

(* For each row, convert and append element *)
For[r = 1, r <= Length[Ktxt], r++,
 t = StringSplit[Ktxt[[r]]];
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[t], i += 2,
  s1 = (convert[StringReplace[t[[i]], {"(" -> "", "," -> ""}]])[[1]];
  s2 = (convert[StringReplace[t[[i + 1]], ")" -> ""]])[[1]];
  AppendTo[l, {r, s1 + 1} -> s2]
  ];
 If[Mod[r, 100] == 0, Print["row ", r]]
 ]

(* Make the sparse matrix *)
MM = SparseArray[l]
```

Is there a way to make this faster? For a `15,000 x 15,000` matrix with `800,000` non-zero elements it takes hours.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not have PETSc save your matrix to a format that *Mathematica* can `Import[]`, like *.mtx?

Comment: First, I am not skilled in PETSc, which is one package used by another software I am using, and second, my goal is to improve my Mathematica knowledge.

Comment: Please provide a sample `aij` matrix file (or code that generates its content) -- it is much more likely to get responses to your question.

Comment: I modified the question: that sample code is the file itself, actually.

Comment: cant test here, but what does `Import[..,"Table"]` do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing string operations on a much finer granularity level than necessary. The code below is fairly fast on my computer for matrices with the size and fill-in you mention.

### Data generation

Since no data was provided in the question let us generate such data.

```
smat = AdjacencyMatrix[RandomGraph[{15000, 400000}]]

Dimensions[smat]    
(* {15000, 15000} *)

smat["Density"]*Apply[Times, Dimensions[smat]]    
(* 800000. *)


exportRows = 
  Map[{#[[1, 1, 1]], 
     Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 2]], RandomReal[{0, 10}, Length[#]]}]} &, 
   GatherBy[Most[ArrayRules[smat]], #[[1, 1]] &]];

aijText = 
  StringJoin@
   Riffle[Map[
     ToString[#[[1]]] <> ":" <> 
       StringReplace[
        StringTake[ToString[#[[2]]], {2, -2}], {"{" -> "(", 
         "}" -> ")", "," ->" " }] &, exportRows], "\n"];

 StringLength[aijText]

 (* 13872182 *)
```

### Conversion

Here is the conversion code. Note the use of `Cases` to eliminate wrong parsings. (I was too lazy to identify the reason, for smaller matrices the process happens without problems...)

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 t1 = StringReplace[
  aijText, {")" ~~ (WhitespaceCharacter ..) ~~ "(" -> "},{", 
  "(" -> "{", ")" -> "}", 
   x : NumberString ~~ (WhitespaceCharacter ..) ~~ y : NumberString :> x <> "," <> y}];
]

(* {1.534615, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 triplets = Flatten[#, 1] &@
    Map[Flatten /@ Thread[#] &,
     Map[{ToExpression[#[[1]]], 
        ToExpression["{" <> #[[2]] <> "}"]} &,
      Map[StringCases[#, x__ ~~ ":" ~~ y__ :> {x, y}][[1]] &, 
       StringSplit[t1, "\n"]]]];
 ]

(* {2.763, Null} *)

triplets // Length
(* 799893 *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 triplets = Cases[triplets, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}];
 ]

(* {0.520321, Null} *)

triplets // Length    
(* 799893 *)

smat2 = 
 SparseArray[Thread[#[[All, 1 ;; 2]] -> #[[All, 3]]] &@triplets]
```

Comment: The example in the question doesn't imply `,` between adjacent `)` and `(`. Hence I would replace `StringReplace[aijText, {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}]` with `StringReplace[aijText, {") (" -> "},{", "(" -> "{", ")" -> "}"}]` (assuming one space between adjacent `)` and `(`).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you, for looking into this, I made the related corrections.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I just had to add `triplets = Map[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] + 1, #[[3]]} &, triplets]` to make this work, as the original file starts with zero, and Mathematica complains with `SparseArray::posr: The left-hand side of {0,0}->1 in {{0,0}->1,{0,2}->2,{1,1}->1,{2,0}->-(1/1000),{2,2}->2} is not a position or a pattern that will match the position of an element in an array with depth 2.`. Thanks!

Comment: @senseiwa Ok, I am glad my answer was useful.